Error when generating report with Crystal Reports and ASP.NET MVC
I get an error in my ASP.NET MVC project using C# when I want to export my report to a PDF document to show it in a page.
This is my code:
public FileStreamResult CrearReporte()
{
    try
    {
        var Reporte = new ReportDocument();
        Reporte.Load(Nombre_reporte);

        // agrega los parametros usados en el reporte
        if (ListaParametros.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= ListaParametros.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                Reporte.SetParameterValue(ListaParametros[x].NombreParametro,ListaParametros[x].ValorParamentro);
            }
        }

        // Configura las credenciales de la base de datos
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        connectionInfo.ServerName = this.Nombre_servidor;
        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = this.Nombre_db;
        connectionInfo.UserID = this.Nombre_usuario;
        connectionInfo.Password = this.Password_servidor;

        // Obtén la colección de tablas del informe y actualiza las credenciales para cada tabla
        TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        Tables tables = Reporte.Database.Tables;

        foreach (Table table in tables)
        {
            tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
        }
                
        Stream stream = Reporte.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf") ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}

The error is:

Error: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase+FileStreamDeleteOnClose'

Thank you in advance for your time to help me with my problem.
